# ZedGraph AxisChange() reset?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm using C#. When I use `AxisChange()` to adjust the axis on my graph, it works fine, until I go into the graph pane and manually zoom in and out.

After manually zooming in and out, the `AxisChange()` command no longer works. How can you get it so after the axis gets fixed, you can again use `AxisChange()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the code of AxisChange() method and I think this is because of following code:

```
            // if the ChartRect is not yet determined, then pick a scale based on a default ChartRect
        // size (using 75% of Rect -- code is in Axis.CalcMaxLabels() )
        // With the scale picked, call CalcChartRect() so calculate a real ChartRect
        // then let the scales re-calculate to make sure that the assumption was ok
        if ( _chart._isRectAuto )
        {
            PickScale( g, scaleFactor );

            _chart._rect = CalcChartRect( g );
            //this.pieRect = PieItem.CalcPieRect( g, this, scaleFactor, this.chartRect );
        }
```

I’m not sure though, you should give a try copy line … outside the “if” clause and see what happens. Any way, try to debug the source code, it is good enough for understanding.

Comment: Do you know how to disable manual zooming and resizing so i can avoid this entirely?